# Decimal counter JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, counter

i want to build a decimal counter in pure JavaScript. I don't know why the function doesn't want to work and count from 0.0 to 5.1. I am assuming that the problem is with Math.round - maybe it's defined in the wrong way.

HTML:

```
<span id="values">5.1</span>
<span id="counter"></span>
```

JS:

```
var numbers = document.getElementById('values').innerHTML;
var i = 0;                    

function countUp () {           
   setTimeout(function () {    
      document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i;
      this.i(Math.round(now*10)/10);
      i++;                     
      if (i <= numbers) { 
         countUp();           
      }                       
   }, 5000)
}

countUp();
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what exactly doesn't work? Are you seeing any messages in the error console?

Comment: `i` is not a function.... yet you are trying to call it as one

Comment: @PatrickEvans so how can i change it? like just this.(Math.round(now*10)/10); ?

Comment: @petlet `i = (Math.round(now*10)/10);` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Number#toFixed` to get rid of the unwanted floating point numbers.

```js
function countUp () {
    var numbers = document.getElementById('values').innerHTML,
        i = 0,
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            i = +(i + 0.1).toFixed(1);
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i;
            if (i >= +numbers) { 
               clearInterval(interval );           
            }          
        }, 100);
}

countUp();
```

```html
<span id="values">5.1</span>
<span id="counter"></span>
```